# How do I prevent entity framework from creating extra tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an issue when I upgraded entity framework to 5.0, to illustrate:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public Foo foo;

   public ICollection<Student> Students{ get; set; }

}

public class Student
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string s {get; set;}
}

public class Foo
{
  public int data {get; set}
  ...
}
```

EF correctly creates a table called Students because I have defined a one-to-many relationship from MyClass to Student. I am using class Foo as encapsulation and have a 1-to-1 relationship.

EF 4.0 did not create a separate table for `Foo`, instead used the property data as `Foo_data` within the MyClass table. With EF 5.0 I am getting another table for `Foo`.

How can I tell EF not to create a table for `Foo`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure why/how this has changed from EF4 but what you want is `Foo` to be a [Complex Type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/03/28/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types.aspx). That should have been derived from the fact that `Foo` has no `Id` property.
Try to enforce it:

```
[ComplexType]
public class Foo
{
  public int data {get; set}
  ...
}
```

Comment: Henk, great, I will try that, the solution makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when trying to Migrate in EF5. I found that EntityFramework had automatically added a `DbSet` property to my `DbContext`. It was hidden right at the bottom of the class.

I think this had to do with selecting it as a ViewModel when generating a view and supplying a  DbContext. Don't supply the dbContext.